# Unable to Launch Game on Arch Linux Via Steam

Tags: linux, crash, steam, arch, proton-native

I am trying to start Civilization 5 on a Arch Linux System using Steam/Lutris. The game launches fine until the map is ready to be displayed. Once the map is ready to be displayed and the game has finished loading up, the game just closes out with no presentable error message. Any ideas on how to solve this problem would be greatly appreciated!

Below I have posted the log:

```
lutris-wrapper: Sid Meier's Civilization V
Started initial process 11254 from /usr/bin/steam steam://rungameid/8930
Start monitoring process.
Running Steam on arch rolling 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Steam runtime environment up-to-date!
Steam client's requirements are satisfied
WARNING: Using default/fallback debugger launch
/home/its/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam steam://rungameid/8930
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1634158817)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1634158817)
Loaded SDL version 2.0.17-6744061
/usr/share/themes/Breeze/gtk-2.0/widgets/entry:70: error: unexpected identifier `direction', expected character `}'

(steam:11385): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "adwaita",
/usr/share/themes/Breeze/gtk-2.0/widgets/styles:36: error: invalid string constant "combobox_entry", expected valid string constant
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1634158817)
Fontconfig warning: line 5: unknown element "description"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-hinting-slight.conf", line 4: unknown element "description"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 4: unknown element "description"
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 72: non-double matrix element
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 72: non-double matrix element
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 80: saw unknown, expected number
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/20-unhint-small-vera.conf", line 4: unknown element "description"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 4: unknown element "description"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/40-nonlatin.conf", line 4: unknown element "description"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/45-generic.conf", line 4: unknown element "description"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/45-latin.conf", line 4: unknown element "description"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/49-sansserif.conf", line 4: unknown element "description"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/50-user.conf", line 4: unknown element "description"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/51-local.conf", line 4: unknown element "description"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/60-generic.conf", line 4: unknown element "description"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/60-latin.conf", line 4: unknown element "description"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/65-nonlatin.conf", line 4: unknown element "description"
Runtime for steamwebhelper: defaulting to /home/its/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_64/steam-runtime-heavy
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1634158817)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1634158817)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1634158817)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1634158817)
CAppInfoCacheReadFromDiskThread took 40 milliseconds to initialize
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1634158817)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1634158817)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1634158817)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1634158817)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1634158817)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1634158817)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1634158817)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1634158817)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1634158817)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1634158817)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1634158817)
Proceed to auto login
Opted-in Controller Mask for AppId 0: 0
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1634158817)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1634158817)

(steam:11385): Gtk-WARNING **: gtk_disable_setlocale() must be called before gtk_init()
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1634158817)
roaming config store loaded successfully - 520 bytes.
migrating temporary roaming config store
BRefreshApplicationsInLibrary 1: 13ms
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1634158817)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1634158817)
Failed to init SteamVR because it isn't installed
ExecCommandLine: "'/home/its/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam' 'steam://rungameid/8930'"
ExecuteSteamURL: "steam://rungameid/8930"
System startup time: 4.00 seconds
GameAction [AppID 8930, ActionID 1] : LaunchApp changed task to ProcessingInstallScript with ""
GameAction [AppID 8930, ActionID 1] : LaunchApp changed task to SynchronizingCloud with ""
GameAction [AppID 8930, ActionID 1] : LaunchApp changed task to SiteLicenseSeatCheckout with ""
GameAction [AppID 8930, ActionID 1] : LaunchApp changed task to CreatingProcess with ""
GameAction [AppID 8930, ActionID 1] : LaunchApp waiting for user response to CreatingProcess ""
GameAction [AppID 8930, ActionID 1] : LaunchApp continues with user response "CreatingProcess"
Opted-in Controller Mask for AppId 8930: 0
/bin/sh\0-c\0taskset -c 0-1 /home/its/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/reaper SteamLaunch AppId=8930 -- '/home/its/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/Sid Meier'\''s Civilization V/./Civ5XP'\0
Game process added : AppID 8930 "taskset -c 0-1 /home/its/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/reaper SteamLaunch AppId=8930 -- '/home/its/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/Sid Meier'\''s Civilization V/./Civ5XP'", ProcID 11616, IP 0.0.0.0:0
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/its/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
GameAction [AppID 8930, ActionID 1] : LaunchApp changed task to WaitingGameWindow with ""
GameAction [AppID 8930, ActionID 1] : LaunchApp changed task to Completed with ""
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/its/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/its/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_64/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/its/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_64/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64): ignored.
BuildCompleteAppOverviewChange: 108
RegisterForAppOverview 1: 35ms
RegisterForAppOverview 2: 35ms
Game process updated : AppID 8930 "taskset -c 0-1 /home/its/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/reaper SteamLaunch AppId=8930 -- '/home/its/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/Sid Meier'\''s Civilization V/./Civ5XP'", ProcID 11623, IP 0.0.0.0:0
Setting breakpad minidump AppID = 8930
Steam_SetMinidumpSteamID:  Caching Steam ID:  76561198170349193 [API loaded no]
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1634158817)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1634158817)
GUID Assets\dlc\dlc_01\mongol.civ5pkg 7a036b7fb9a80e8dea7b73fb58c5a288
GUID Assets\dlc\dlc_02\spaininca.civ5pkg 4f75e72761f4c6019b55a0a7b90444a2
GUID Assets\dlc\dlc_03\polynesia.civ5pkg 99ac9d5f6ca4b5bed0ab89c0fd3b9e6d
GUID Assets\dlc\dlc_04\denmark.civ5pkg 0efb155307bd6d14c9290b49b5364a3e
GUID Assets\dlc\dlc_05\korea.civ5pkg 9f4df81cf712ae9480737f816bf6f4c8
GUID Assets\dlc\dlc_06\ancientwonders.civ5pkg 92b102db9a3c7dc068030c3ce33bbb48
GUID Assets\dlc\dlc_07\civcomplete.civ5pkg eb01a0be4d8e5312f53b042c8a7c30b5
GUID Assets\dlc\dlc_deluxe\babylon.civ5pkg 712495341921f2b288746c6d44fd6867
GUID Assets\dlc\dlc_sp_maps\dlc_sp_maps.civ5pkg 52b285c37939913e0a5b72933bb06067
GUID Assets\dlc\dlc_sp_maps_2\dlc_sp_maps_2.civ5pkg 16a61e7a2a7bb4bc2d1f677b5bb58ff4
GUID Assets\dlc\dlc_sp_maps_3\dlc_sp_maps_3.civ5pkg 1954db58e0a60b018969c49440fa01ef
GUID Assets\dlc\expansion\expansion1.civ5pkg 8bc30c58378345cb0911c5848926f1ff
GUID Assets\dlc\expansion2\expansion2.civ5pkg 31dfaa9838c5b051d4c2112ddd9e7eb3
GUID Assets\dlc\shared\upgrade1.civ5pkg e818fa28902977b42ee5e3426f5112e6
number - table
number - table
number - table
number - table
/home/its/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/Sid Meier's Civilization V/steamassets/controller.vdf
Game process removed: AppID 8930 "taskset -c 0-1 /home/its/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/reaper SteamLaunch AppId=8930 -- '/home/its/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/Sid Meier'\''s Civilization V/./Civ5XP'", ProcID 11623 
Game 8930 created interface STEAMAPPS_INTERFACE_VERSION006 / Apps
Game 8930 created interface STEAMCONTROLLER_INTERFACE_VERSION / Controller
Game 8930 created interface STEAMHTTP_INTERFACE_VERSION002 / HTTP
Game 8930 created interface STEAMREMOTESTORAGE_INTERFACE_VERSION012 / RemoteStorage
Game 8930 created interface STEAMSCREENSHOTS_INTERFACE_VERSION002 / Screenshots
Game 8930 created interface STEAMUGC_INTERFACE_VERSION001 / UGC
Game 8930 created interface STEAMUNIFIEDMESSAGES_INTERFACE_VERSION001 / UnifiedMessages
Game 8930 created interface STEAMUSERSTATS_INTERFACE_VERSION011 / UserStats
Game 8930 created interface SteamFriends014 / Friends
Game 8930 created interface SteamMatchMaking009 / Matchmaking
Game 8930 created interface SteamMatchMakingServers002 / MatchmakingServers
Game 8930 created interface SteamNetworking005 / Networking
Game 8930 created interface SteamUser017 / User
Game 8930 created interface SteamUtils006 / Utils
Game 8930 method call count for IClientUserStats::GetAchievementDisplayAttribute : 572
Game 8930 method call count for IClientUserStats::GetAchievement : 303
Game 8930 method call count for IClientUserStats::GetStat : 137
Game 8930 method call count for IClientUserStats::RequestCurrentStats : 1
Game 8930 method call count for IClientAppManager::GetCurrentLanguage : 6
Game 8930 method call count for IClientAppManager::BIsDlcEnabled : 13
Game 8930 method call count for IClientUtils::RecordSteamInterfaceCreation : 15
Game 8930 method call count for IClientUtils::GetAppID : 32
Game 8930 method call count for IClientUser::BIsSubscribedApp : 13
Game 8930 method call count for IClientUser::GetSteamID : 1
Game 8930 method call count for IClientUser::BLoggedOn : 3
Uploaded AppInterfaceStats to Steam
No cached sticky mapping in ActivateActionSet.ExecuteSteamURL: "steam://rungameid/8930"
GameAction [AppID 8930, ActionID 2] : LaunchApp changed task to ProcessingInstallScript with ""
GameAction [AppID 8930, ActionID 2] : LaunchApp changed task to SynchronizingCloud with ""
GameAction [AppID 8930, ActionID 2] : LaunchApp changed task to SiteLicenseSeatCheckout with ""
GameAction [AppID 8930, ActionID 2] : LaunchApp changed task to CreatingProcess with ""
GameAction [AppID 8930, ActionID 2] : LaunchApp waiting for user response to CreatingProcess ""
GameAction [AppID 8930, ActionID 2] : LaunchApp continues with user response "CreatingProcess"
/bin/sh\0-c\0taskset -c 0-1 /home/its/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/reaper SteamLaunch AppId=8930 -- '/home/its/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/Sid Meier'\''s Civilization V/./Civ5XP'\0
Game process added : AppID 8930 "taskset -c 0-1 /home/its/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/reaper SteamLaunch AppId=8930 -- '/home/its/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/Sid Meier'\''s Civilization V/./Civ5XP'", ProcID 11889, IP 0.0.0.0:0
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/its/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
GameAction [AppID 8930, ActionID 2] : LaunchApp changed task to WaitingGameWindow with ""
GameAction [AppID 8930, ActionID 2] : LaunchApp changed task to Completed with ""
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/its/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/its/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_64/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/its/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_64/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64): ignored.
Game process updated : AppID 8930 "taskset -c 0-1 /home/its/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/reaper SteamLaunch AppId=8930 -- '/home/its/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/Sid Meier'\''s Civilization V/./Civ5XP'", ProcID 11891, IP 0.0.0.0:0
Setting breakpad minidump AppID = 8930
Steam_SetMinidumpSteamID:  Caching Steam ID:  76561198170349193 [API loaded no]
XXX: resource creation failed
XXX: resource creation failed
XXX: resource creation failed
XXX: resource creation failed
XXX: resource creation failed
Game process removed: AppID 8930 "taskset -c 0-1 /home/its/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/reaper SteamLaunch AppId=8930 -- '/home/its/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/Sid Meier'\''s Civilization V/./Civ5XP'", ProcID 11891 
Game 8930 created interface STEAMAPPS_INTERFACE_VERSION006 / Apps
Game 8930 created interface STEAMCONTROLLER_INTERFACE_VERSION / Controller
Game 8930 created interface STEAMHTTP_INTERFACE_VERSION002 / HTTP
Game 8930 created interface STEAMREMOTESTORAGE_INTERFACE_VERSION012 / RemoteStorage
Game 8930 created interface STEAMSCREENSHOTS_INTERFACE_VERSION002 / Screenshots
Game 8930 created interface STEAMUGC_INTERFACE_VERSION001 / UGC
Game 8930 created interface STEAMUNIFIEDMESSAGES_INTERFACE_VERSION001 / UnifiedMessages
Game 8930 created interface STEAMUSERSTATS_INTERFACE_VERSION011 / UserStats
Game 8930 created interface SteamFriends014 / Friends
Game 8930 created interface SteamMatchMaking009 / Matchmaking
Game 8930 created interface SteamMatchMakingServers002 / MatchmakingServers
Game 8930 created interface SteamNetworking005 / Networking
Game 8930 created interface SteamUser017 / User
Game 8930 created interface SteamUtils006 / Utils
Game 8930 method call count for IClientUserStats::GetAchievementDisplayAttribute : 572
Game 8930 method call count for IClientUserStats::GetAchievement : 303
Game 8930 method call count for IClientUserStats::StoreStats : 1
Game 8930 method call count for IClientUserStats::SetStat : 19
Game 8930 method call count for IClientUserStats::GetStat : 156
Game 8930 method call count for IClientUserStats::RequestCurrentStats : 1
Game 8930 method call count for IClientAppManager::GetCurrentLanguage : 6
Game 8930 method call count for IClientAppManager::BIsDlcEnabled : 13
Game 8930 method call count for IClientUtils::RecordSteamInterfaceCreation : 15
Game 8930 method call count for IClientUtils::GetAppID : 33
Game 8930 method call count for IClientUser::BIsSubscribedApp : 13
Game 8930 method call count for IClientUser::GetSteamID : 1
Game 8930 method call count for IClientUser::BLoggedOn : 3
Uploaded AppInterfaceStats to Steam
No cached sticky mapping in ActivateActionSet.
```

Answer (score 1):

I have been searching on the internet for a while and found the solution in [this](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux/issues/4483) Github issue.
What worked for me is to put this in the launch options in Steam:

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib32/libopenal.so.1 %command%
```

You may have to install the package steam-native first.

Edit:
To anyone reading this: nowadays, you are probably better of installing Civ 5 via Proton (look up force proton online)